# Traverse zip file using VBA

Tags: excel, zip, vba

I need to traverse a zip files using VBA. In particular I need to, without unzipping the file, locate the ***xl*** folder in order to find the ***media*** subfolder. I then need to copy the images out of the media subfolder and save them to another folder.

```
Public Sub Extract_Images()
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim objFile As File
Dim myFolder
Const zipDir As String = "\\...\ZIP FILES"
Const xlFolder As String = "xl"
Const mediaFolder  As String = "media"
Dim picname As String
Dim zipname As String

Set fso = New FileSystemObject
Set myFolder = fso.GetFolder(zipDir)

For Each objFile In myFolder.Files
zipname = objFile.Name

Next objFile

End Sub
```

^That code successfully loops through the folder and gathers the names of the zip files. But I need to get into the files and traverse the structures to get to the Media folder.

Comment: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s7/win002.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building off: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s7/win002.htm

**Edit:** - this shows how you can incorporate the extraction into your code.  Just pass the full zip path and the location to where you want to extract the files.  You can do this from within your existing loop.

You may need to account for media files sharing the same name if you're planning on extracting them all to the same location...

```
Sub Tester()

    ExtractMediaFiles "C:\Users\twilliams\Desktop\tempo.zip", _
                 "C:\Users\twilliams\Desktop\extracted\"

End Sub



Sub ExtractMediaFiles(zipFile As Variant, outFolder As Variant)

    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim fileNameInZip As Variant, oNS As Object

    Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

    On Error Resume Next
    Set oNS = oApp.Namespace(zipFile & "\xl\media")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not oNS Is Nothing Then
        For Each fileNameInZip In oNS.items
            Debug.Print fileNameInZip
            oApp.Namespace(outFolder).copyhere oNS.items.Item(CStr(fileNameInZip))
        Next
    Else
        Debug.Print "No xl\media path for " & zipFile
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: That's not penetrating the zip files - unless I missing something ? That tells me there are no media files in the parent folder.

Comment: It worked for me in testing: I saved an xlsx as "tempo.xlsx", renamed it to "tempo.zip", then ran that code.  I'm assuming your "zip" files are really xlsx files with a zip extension ?  Obviously you're going to need to make some changes to incorporate this into your existing code.

Comment: ^ I think it is an directory issue, and yes I ran code to change all of my xls/xlsx file to zip extensions. I  am assuming the  Fname is the folder holding all the zip files?

Comment: Perhaps it is more subtle but we are not "getting into" the zip files. Debug.Print reads :  No xl\media path for \\........ \ZIP Files ; which is false. I believe your code is looking for "media files" in the Fname folder and not within the actual zip files.

Comment: You need to pass *each zip file* into that Sub, not the path to the folder containing the files.