# How to open a sheet I've just unzipped in Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to write some macros in both Excel and Outlook that in the end will automatically unzip and open a CSV, process the data, and sends it where it needs to go when a new email arrives in a specific folder. I have everything worked out on the Excel side but I am having difficulties with Outlook. The below code unzips the file. How would i go about opening the unzipped file and triggering an Excel macro (which is always open in another workbook)?

Another issue I am running into: this code only seems to work when i actually open the target email in it's own window.

```
Public Sub OpenZippedSheet()
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim objAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim objShell As Object
    Dim objFileSystem As Object
    Dim strTempFolder As String
    Dim strFilePath As String
    Dim strFileName As String

    Set objMail = Outlook.Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    Set objAttachments = objMail.Attachments

    'Save & Unzip the zip file in local drive
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    strTempFolder = objFileSystem.GetSpecialFolder(2).Path & "\Temp" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss")
    MkDir (strTempFolder)

    For Each objAttachment In objAttachments
        If Right(objAttachment.FileName, 3) = "zip" Then
           strFilePath = strTempFolder & "\" & objAttachment.FileName
           objAttachment.SaveAsFile (strFilePath)
           objShell.NameSpace((strTempFolder)).CopyHere objShell.NameSpace((strFilePath)).Items
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

I'm assuming I would do some sort of object.open but I don't know what the syntax would be to get it to actually open in Excel. And then is there a way to trigger an Excel macro from Outlook?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Is Excel already open when your Outlook macro runs?  Is there only a single file in the attached zip archive, and do you know the names(s) of the contained files? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44788853/traverse-zip-file-using-vba/44789307#44789307 for how to look at the zip contents and find the file(s) you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> this code only seems to work when i actually open the target email in it's own window.

That is because you rely on the `ActiveInspector` window. If you want to handle items selected in the Explorer windows you need to check the `Selection` object (see the corresponding property).

To open an Excel file you can:

1. Use the [Shell.ShellExecute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-shellexecute) method. This method is equivalent to launching one of the commands associated with a file's shortcut menu. Each command is represented by a verb string. The set of supported verbs varies from file to file. The most commonly supported verb is "open", which is also usually the default verb. Other verbs might be supported by only certain types of files.
2. Automate Excel from your VBA macro to do the required actions. See [How to automate Microsoft Excel from Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/automate-excel-from-visual-basic) for more information.

To run your VBA macro code from other applications you can use the `Application.Run` method. Read more about that in the [How do I use Application.Run in Excel](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win001.htm) article.

```
Application.Run "'" & TestWkbk.Name & "'!MacroNameHere", "parm1", "parm2"
```

Comment: CreateObject("Shell.Application").Open (strTempFolder & "\" & objAttachment.FileName) Does not seem to work for me. I'm getting an Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: Did you try to use the `ShellExecute` method instead?

Comment: Okay so i got it to work with Shex as shell.app and then: `Shex.Open ("C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Temp\Temp2019-07-23-17-28-58\test.csv")` but it will not work with `Shex.Open (strTempFolder & "\" & objAttachment.FileName)` Do you know why that might be?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (untested so may need some fixes):

```
'Note - any paths passed to objShell should be
'       passed as *Variants*, not Strings
Dim oXL As Object, wbCSV As Object, fileNameInZip As Variant


Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

For Each objAttachment In objAttachments
    If Right(objAttachment.Filename, 3) = "zip" Then

        strFilePath = strTempFolder & "\" & objAttachment.Filename
        objAttachment.SaveAsFile strFilePath
        Set oNS = oApp.Namespace(strFilePath)

        For Each fileNameInZip In oNS.items 'loop over the files in the zip
            Debug.Print fileNameInZip
            If LCase(fileNameInZip) Like "*.csv" Then 'csv file?
                'extract the file
                objShell.Namespace(strTempFolder).copyhere oNS.items.Item(CStr(fileNameInZip))

                If oXL Is Nothing Then Set oXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application") 'assumes excel is running
                Set wbCSV = oXL.Workbooks.Open(strTempFolder & "\" & fileNameInZip)

                oXL.Run "'YourMacroFile.xlsm'!YourMacroName" 'run the macro
                'clean up stuff...

            End If 'is a csv file
        Next 'file in zip

    End If 'attachment is a zip file
Next 'attachment
```